# Relation between limit and limsup

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

There's a clain in Folands analysis book:

$\lim_{r \rightarrow R} \phi(r) = c$ iff $\limsup_{r \rightarrow R} |\phi(r) - c| = 0$

The forward direction is obvious to me, the reverse direction is no so obvious. In particular, isn't it true that:
$$\limsup_{r \rightarrow R} |\phi(r) - c| = 0 \implies \limsup_{r \rightarrow R} \phi(r) = c$$

Without any more information about $\phi$ there's nothing to be said about the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_r\geq 0$ for every $r$ and $\limsup_{r\to R} a_r=0$ then also $\liminf_{r\to R}a_r=0$ because $$0\leq\liminf_{r\to R}a_r\leq\limsup_{r\to R}a_r$$

Then consequently $\lim_{r\to R}a_r$ exists and equals $0$.

Applying that we find that $\lim_{r\to R}|\phi(r)-c|=0$ which is actually the same statement as $\lim_{r\to R}\phi(r)=c$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$0=\limsup_{r\to R}\left|\phi(r)-c\right|\geq \liminf_{r\to R}\left|\phi(r)-c\right|\geq 0 $$